# iTerm2 - Accessibility and Full Disk Access

Tags: macos, permission, mojave, iterm, privacy

Just installed iTerm2 and it asked me change some settings in Security & Privacy of macOS.
At the moment I gave "Full Disk Access". Under "Accessibility" I see iTerm2 listed but without the checkbox unchecked.

Shall I give iTerm2 both "Full Disk Access" and "Accessibility" permission? Or shall I revoke any permission?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to access special directories/files such as `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook` or `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary`, yes you need to give Full Disk Access to iTerm2. If don't, you can not access those directories.

For more information, here is the iTerm2 wiki https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/fulldiskaccess

Here is the screenshot when you don't give Full Disk Access to iTerm2.

[image: iTerm2 don't have Full Disk Access]

Comment: What about "Accessibility" permission?

Comment: In Accessibility I see AEServer and Terminal. I added iterm from Applications. There is no iterm2 which should be. In Full Disk Access I also added Iterm. It is working now, I want to access the downloads folder.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to add the mentioned permission?

Comment: To enable access to photos, simply toggle the switch in the Photos section of the Privacy & Security settings.