# Why does the Terminal app need access to Contacts?

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, catalina

In Security and Privacy, Terminal has access to Contacts.  It also has access to Calendars, Reminders, and Photos.

Why does Terminal have access to them? I do not know of any Terminal feature which requires them.

[image]

Comment: searching like `find` etc, can require access to contacts

Comment: @anki: why would `find` require access to contacts?!

Comment: @smci if a program wants to read files related to contacts like in user Library folder , macos takes it as wanting access to contacts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn’t need access - say no to the request.

Unless you want [some program](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341644/iterm2-accessibility-and-full-disk-access) that runs inside terminal to look at your user data, just decline these requests.

This is covered in the security part **Data protections** - https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/features/ - you are seeing the ask to allow looking into that data store / folder.